# How to inherit undefined variables with Jinja2?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In my Ansible roles, some roles derive specific configuration settings from global variables Global variables might be undefined. The following code illustrates the schema:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    bar: '{{ foo }}'
  tasks:
    # Assume foo comes from an Ansible environment
    - debug: var=foo
    # Assume bar comes from a role default
    - debug: var=bar
    # Catched by the "is defined" condition
    - debug: msg="foo is defined"
      when: 'foo is defined'
    # Cannot catch undefined exception?!
    - debug: msg="bar is defined"
      when: 'bar is defined'
```

Everything works as expected, but the last statement: Ansible raises an exception because `foo` is undefined (yes, it is undefined).

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "bar": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'bar is defined' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (bar is defined): {{ foo }}: 'foo' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '.../test-undef.yml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      when: 'foo is defined'\n    - debug: msg=\"bar is defined\"\n      ^ here\n"}
```

So why does `bar` not “evaluate” to `undefined` like `foo`? And how can I trap this “multi-level” undefinedness?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    bar: '{{ foo }}'
  tasks:
    # Assume foo comes from an Ansible environment
    - debug: var=vars.foo
    # Assume bar comes from a role default
    - debug: var=vars.bar
    # Catched by the "is defined" condition
    - debug: msg="foo is defined"
      when: vars.foo is defined
    # Cannot catch undefined exception?!
    - debug: msg="bar is defined"
      when: vars.bar is defined
```

Comment: @Frenchy: Yes, indeed... And if you run my script then you will see that it runs fine...

Comment: yes...i agree with you,

Comment: Thanks, @Swifty. However, Ansible shows `vars.bar` as _defined_ with your code:
```text
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "bar is defined"
}
```
Probably because it holds the template string?

Comment: yes its right, so foo is defined implies bar defined

Comment: But `foo` is not defined …

Comment: foo not defined implies bar not defined..you just have to check if foo is defined to check if bar is defined

Comment: @Stephan Please understand the difference between `'{{ foo }}'` and `"{{ foo }}"`...
`"{{ foo }}"` means a variable... `'{{ foo }}'` means literally that string...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that bar is technically defined, and your definition of `bar` uses a possibly undefined variable. When you attempt to do anything with `bar` it has to be evaluated as an independent Jinja expression, which happens before the `is defined` check.

One way to address this is to make it so `bar` can be evaluated without resulting in an undefined value, e.g.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    bar: "{{ foo | default(false) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: bar is truthy
      when: bar is truthy
```

You can also check foo before bar since evaluation is short-circuitable, but baking knowledge of the variable relationship into your tasks can be unwieldy.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    bar: "{{ foo }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: bar is truthy
      when: 
        - foo is defined
        - bar is defined
```

Comment: Please note that @Stephan defined the bar variable as a string! `bar: '{{ foo }}'` literally means a sting!!!

Answer (score -1):

try adding

```
when: ( vars[bar] is defined )
```

Comment: vars is an undocumented internal implementation that may be removed in the future and should not be used.